# Problem grouping rows into columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a dashboard. I have a data source that contains a column with values ​​separated by commas. I am trying to group rows using these columns. Yet,
Values ​​are not classified by default. That way, I can have something like this:

```
Line 1 - A, B, C
Line 2 - C, B, A
Line 3 - A
Line 4 - B, C
Line 5 - C, B
Line 6 - A
```

What I want to achieve is a grouping like this:

```
A, B, C - Line 1 and Line 2
A - line 3 and line 6
B, C - line 4 and line 5
```

I thought about dividing the CSV into columns, classifying them and finally joining them again as CSV, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI's best functionality for this task is in the Power Query editor - from the Home ribbon choose **Transform data**.

In the Power Query window, select the column you want to edit and choose **Split Column / By Delimiter**. There are lots of options, including a nice feature in the Advanced section of the Split column pop-up to split onto rows instead of columns.

I couldn't really follow the detail of your requirements, but hopefully that's enough to get you started.  If not please add screenshots of what your data looks like and what you want to produce.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below **Power Query Editor** code to edit your table in the **Advanced Editor**. This will add a new column to your table applying **Ascending Order** to the Comma separated values-

```
let
    //Existing steps
    ,
    #"Add column" = 
        Table.AddColumn(
            #"Previous_Step_Name", 
            "Custom", 
            each Text.Combine(
                List.Sort(
                    List.ReplaceValue(
                        Text.Split([Your_current_column_name], ", "), 
                        " ", 
                        "", 
                        Replacer.ReplaceText
                    )
                )
                ,", "
            )
        )
in
    #"Add column"
```

Here is the output-

[image]

You can now easily apply **GROUP BY** on the new column created.